# How to iterate a command over a set of files?

Tags: shell, pipe, wildcards, control-flow

I have a folder full of files with a `.dot` extension like this:

```
a.dot
b.dot
c.dot
```

I want to go through all the files in this folder and run a command on them such as this:

```
dot -Tpdf a.dot -o a.pdf
dot -Tpdf b.dot -o b.pdf
dot -Tpdf c.dot -o c.pdf
```

I am guessing that I need to use the vertical bar and do a command like this:

```
ls *.dot | dot -Tpdf ... -o ....pdf
```

But I don't know how to make the pipe place each file onto the middle part only. Should I be using `xargs`? Furthermore, how to strip the extension then also place it onto the second part. If I could be at least pointed in the right direction (which shell command to use) it would help me very far along the way to figuring this out.

Comment: [Do not parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The shell performs wildcard expansion (e.g. of `*.dot` into `a.dot b.dot c.dot`); `ls` is a tool intended for humans, when you want to display file attributes (size, date, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
for i in *.dat ; do dot -Tpdf "$i" -o "$(basename "$i" dot)pdf" ; done
```

**EDIT:**
Correct handling of filenames with whitespaces.

Comment: @Peter.O BTW, my origin answer without quotes works correctly in `zsh`, which I use, even for filenames with whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In general, unless specifically stated, as you have now done, it is typically better to present the most *portable* syntax. [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)  being the definitive standard...

Answer (score 3):

[xargs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xargs.1.html) is another method to iterate over a set of filenames. However, you don't have the same flexibility as a for-loop to manipulate the filename in each iteration:

```
ls *.dot | xargs -n1 -I FILE echo dot -Tpdf FILE -o FILE.pdf
```

will result in

```
dot -Tpdf a.dot -o a.dot.pdf
dot -Tpdf b.dot -o b.dot.pdf
dot -Tpdf c.dot -o c.dot.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a fan of `awk` and `sed` you can also achieve this with

```
ls *.dot | awk '{print("dot -Tpdf "$1" -o "$1)}' | sed 's/.dot/.pdf/2' | sh
```